# How to setup Selenium tests properly

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a project for testing purpose and I am looking for the best approach.

First of all, I want to have a maven project with spring-boot, selenium, and JUnit5.

I want to have flow like this:

LoginTest -> AnotherTest1 -> ... -> AnotherTest2 -> Logout

I have found that JUnit5 supports something called SuiteClasses annotation so I could have like TestRunner class with annotations:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)               
@Suite.SuiteClasses({               
  LoginTest.class,
  AnotherTest1.class,
  AnotherTest2.class,
  LogoutTest.class,             
})
```

It's okay, it is fine.

Next problem is that I want to have my Webdriver always open thought all tests and to be closed at the end.

In TestNG there is annotation @AfterSuite, I don't know how to reach the same in JUnit. Actually, my WebDriver is in singleton wrapper to use the same instance in every Test.

I was wondering if opening browser at every test would be better - after Login test I would store all cookies and apply them to other tests to be already logged in when I open page.

Comment: Usually you would like your tests to be totally independent, So they should not relay on other tests (or order of it). From your comments it seems that your tests are somewhat relaying on each other.

Comment: @Aviza I don't want to log in every test - this is the only one rule here